# $\frac{1}{t_n-s_n}(-t_ne^{-t_n}-e^{-t_n}+s_ne^{-s_n}+e^{-s_n}) \to 0$, as $t_n-s_n \to +\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function, sequence-of-function

I am trying to show that
$$\frac{1}{t_n-s_n}(-t_ne^{-t_n}-e^{-t_n}+s_ne^{-s_n}+e^{-s_n}) \to 0$$
$$\frac{1}{t_n-s_n}(t_n-e^{-t_n}-s_n+e^{-s_n}) \to 1$$
as $t_n-s_n \to +\infty$, with $t_n > s_n$, $\forall n.$

Any help would be great.

Comment: Take $s_n = -n, t_n = 0$ then both $\to - \infty$.

Comment: yeah these do not hold without some conditions like $s_n\geq 0$ etc.